# Check if the value is an integer in PHP

Tags: php

I am working on a project and in that project I have two objectives

1. I receive data from user
2. I check if the data sent by the user is an `interger` or in case is an integer, if is less than 1

So I wrote this code

```html
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="2"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if (!is_int($_GET['quantity']) || $_GET['quantity'] < 1){
    $_GET['quantity'] = 1;
}

echo $_GET['quantity'];
```

The problem, I am facing is that, the program always echo `1` even if the data is less than 1 or is not an integer at all.

Help me solve this problem please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
if (!is_int($_GET['quantity']) || $_GET['quantity'] < 1){
```

with

```html
$quantity = (int) $_GET['quantity'];

if ($quantity < 1) {...}
```

This casts it to an integer, and if not an integer, casts it as being assigned 0. Then it compares whether it is < 1 or not, and should have the desired result that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, but when I mix integers and letters, it does not work

Comment: @Prince See my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, 'quantity' is actually a string. So when you call

```
is_int($_GET["quantity"))
```

it will always return false, because it is of type string.

The easiest solution would be to convert 'quantity' to an int.

```
is_int((int) $_GET["quantity")
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hope this will help you**

```
$quantity = $_GET['quantity'];
if (!is_numeric($quantity) || $quantity < 1)
{
   $quantity = 1;
}

echo $quantity;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a function to get the integer value of the input.

```
function strtonumber($string = "") {
    $num = intval($string);
    if ($num === 0) {
        $num = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $string);
        $num = intval($num);
    }
    return $num;
}

$quantity = strtonumber($_GET["quantity"]);

if ($quantity < 1) {
    $quantity = 1
}
```

`intval` returns the integer value of the input.

```
echo intval("12ab"); // 12
```

but if the digits come after a letter, it returns `0`.

```
echo intval("ab12"); // 0
```

In that case, to get the `12` from `"ab12"`, we remove any non-digit character and get the integer value again.

The function will always return an integer so you don't need to check if the input is an integer or not.

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work

```
<?php
if (is_numeric($_GET['quantity']) || $_GET['quantity'] < 1){
    $_GET['quantity'] = 1;
}

echo $_GET['quantity'];
```